# What to use instead of route-me library?

Tags: ios, dictionary, offline, route-me

Hi I am an iOS developer and was assigned on developing travel guide apps which uses offline maps in the app. I have successfully developed apps and used a map library called route-me. At first it was okay but the problem occurred when we tried to develop apps for bigger cities/places. The app size is very large because of the map.sqlite file.

I would like to ask for some advise on what library to use instead of route-me to lessen the size of the app. I've heard of using vector based maps but haven't really found one to play around.

P.S.
Our app needs to be totally offline.

Thanks!